# Is there a way to change the built-in controlfx notification popup color?

Tags: java, colors, notifications, javafx-8, controlsfx

[Edit]
here is an exemple of use of the [notification popup](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html) I'm talking about:

```
Notifications.create().title(...).text(...).hideAfter(Duration).show();
```

in this case the notification popup follow the modena style (a little bit gray)

if we add dark style like this:

```
Notifications.create().darkStyle().title(...).text(...).hideAfter(Duration).show();
```

It's shown with dark color

So I just want to know if there is a way to change these default style, I already know about the notification pane and I am not talking about it.

So please I made my homework and did some research ... I found nothing that's why I here to find help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation:
https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/NotificationPane.html

You can take a look at the CSS file for the notification pane here:
/org/controlsfx/control/notificationpane.css

Now you can use the CSS classes in your own stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was'nt talking about the notification pane itself but the notification popup who is shown inside our application depending on a position https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html

Comment: It's the same approach.
In the same package you will find the styleclass for your Notification class: notificationpopup.css

Comment: Thanks Phil, I got it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did:

- I added a new css file named notificationpopup.css as Phil mentionned (thanks to him)
- inside that file i maked changes I added the css file to my primaryStage
- set the owner of my notification popup to this stage
  And it works well now !

---

```
String css = this.getClass().getResource("/views/notificationpopup.css").toExternalForm();
//as my css are in a views package

primaryStage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(css);
Notifications.create().owner(primaryStage).text("my message").hideAfter(new Duration(2000)).showInformation();
```

If you want an example of the notificationpopup.css to make your own visit [the repository of controlfx](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/aca01560384c835a6df2536378cdd0a0602f8a8c/controlsfx/src/main/resources/org/controlsfx/control/notificationpane.css?at=default)

Thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8029271/phil) and the community  for the help